# N-ary tree functions with stdin (makenode, insert)

Tags: c, algorithm, tree

I've tried to code the following functions

```
typedef struct node{
    char *name;
    int n;  //number of kids
    struct node **kids;
    int dtype; // COMPOSITE or BASIC
    union data{
        double price; //for BASIC
        char *quantity; //for COMPOSITE
    }data;
}node;

void create_kid(node **parent){
    if(*parent == NULL){
        (*parent) = malloc(sizeof(node));
        (*parent)->n = 0;
        (*parent)->kids = NULL;
    }else{
        (*parent)->n += 1;
        (*parent)->kids = realloc((*parent)->kids, ((*parent)->n)*(sizeof(node)));
        (*parent)->kids[(*parent)->n - 1] = malloc(sizeof(node));
        (*parent)->kids[(*parent)->n - 1]->n = 0;
        (*parent)->kids[(*parent)->n - 1]->kids = NULL;
    }
}

void insert_c(node *node, char *str){
        node->name = malloc(MAX);
        node->name = str;
        node->dtype = COMPOSITE;
}

void insert_b(node *node, char *str){
        node->name = malloc(MAX);
        node->name = str;
        node->dtype = BASIC;
}
```

to make such an n-ary tree out of an input like this

```
BIKE(2*WHEEL(RIM[60.0 ],
        2*AXLE,
        SPOKE[120.],
        HUB(2*GEAR[25.],AXLE(5*BOLT[0.1], 7 * NUT[.15]))),
    FRAME(REARFRAME [175.00],
        1*FRONTFRAME (FORK[22.5] ,AXLE, 2 *HANDLE[10.])))
```

I am aware of the other representation of an n-ary tree, which includes *siblings, and *firstkid, but I believe this **kids representation is more suitable for my case. I'd like to ask a few things.

Firstly, is there anything wrong with the functions? Are they appropriate to build an n-ary tree?

Secondly, even if I got the functions right, I cannot construct the tree from the input. For example, according to the input, the function calls must be like this with my functions if I read one word at a time:

```
create_kid(&tree);
insert_c(tree, "BIKE");
create_kid(&tree);
insert_c(tree->kids[0], "WHEEL");
create_kid(&(tree->kids[0]));
insert_c(tree->kids[0]->kids[0], "RIM");
.
.
.
create_kid(&tree);
insert_c(tree->kids[1], "FRAME");
.
.
```

If the tree were to be formed in this way, I would need to go from a higher depth to a lower depth, from `NUT` to `FRAME` for example. So I believe there must be an easier way, maybe a recursive approach. Is there any way I can do it with recursion?

Comment: In C I usually advise to make a top level type like "SListTree" or something which then holds the root node. Juggling the tree with only Node instances makes the implementation as well as the using of such a tree much more complicated. Also, the operations you chose look suspicious to bits: Example: createKid() and then inside ``if parent == NULL create a parent``. This looks wrong at first glance. ``SListTreeJoin(SListTree *tree, Node*where, Node*newContent);`` looks a bit better to me. Especially as it looks as if you tried to parse LISP code and transform it into an AST.

Comment: @BitTickler Thank you for your answer. Yes I got a `node *root = NULL` in my code. Also,  I had to add `*parent==NULL` in case I get the root. I will try to write the function as you said. Do you have any advice on reading/building? I didn't know also this was called AST. I was just searching for n-ary, k-ary tree to get informed. At least now I have something closer to look for, thank you.

Comment: If you parse some text according to some grammar, the result is usually called Abstract Syntax Tree (AST). Your LISP-like input (not really lisp but kind of similar) is often called SLIST tree. (Your quantity values in infix notation make the whole thing differ from LISP). Depending on the type of parser you write (bottom up or top down parser), the AST is often composed with a function like I gave above. Accepted productions,yield a Node. If you reach the end of input during parsing, your top level Node is fully constructed and your AST is done.

Comment: @BitTickler Just one last question. The function prototype you gave above is supposed to insert the node at a given place, right? For example, if I were to add a child to root, then calling `SlistTreeJoin(tree, tree->kids[0], temp)` would mean that insertion?

Comment: Yes - if you Join a tree with another (where you have the top node), the other is added to where as a child (kid). Pseudocode: ``SListTreeJoin(tree, where, newNode) { Array.push_back(where->kids, newNode); }``

Comment: BTW: If your first "AXLE" is supposed to be the same as your second "AXLE", your n-ary tree turns into a graph. Or they are two disjoint nodes and it remains a tree.

Comment: @BitTickler It says in the problem "Create only ONE node per part. ie. do not create more then one node if a part is multi
used. (What are pointers for, any way?). In the second example above (the example in
the box), AXLE is multi used. The structure representing AXLE will still be unique. But
There will be pointers pointing to it from the structures representing WHEEL, HUB and
FRONTFRAME.".

I've also changed the structure to `*kids`, `*sibling`. It wouldn't be a problem, would it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Petty things first:

If the same instance of your AXLE node is located at various locations in your "tree", your n-ary tree is not an n-ary tree any longer. It is a graph. If your Axle, then also contained a bike, it would be even a cyclic graph.

You will notice the difference when implementing all that. You will need a reference count or something in a graph to decide when to truly free a node. In a real n-ary tree, you do not need that as each node only occurs once in the tree.

Administrative things next:

You decide to use an array of pointers as data structure to contain the children (kids) of a node. As such, in order to reduce the complexity of the code, it is a good idea to actually create a (dynamic) array of pointers as a first step. Benefits: Your tree code is not burdened with dynamic array code and you can unit test and maybe even re-use your dynamic array of pointers for some other project.

I knocked up a sample pointer array implementation (which is not really deeply tested) to show the principle.

To get the code shown here a bit more "user friendly - first the includes I used, to get that out of the way:

```
#include <crtdbg.h> // Windows specific - helps find memory leaks.
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
```

Now to the Array of pointers implementation:

```
typedef struct PointerArray_tag
{
    void**data;
    size_t capacity;
    size_t size;
} PointerArray_t;

void PointerArrayInitialize(PointerArray_t *array)
{
    array->data = NULL;
    array->capacity = 0;
    array->size = 0;
}

int PointerArrayReserve(PointerArray_t *array, size_t capacity)
{
    if (array->capacity < capacity)
    {
        void **newData = (void**)realloc(array->data, capacity * sizeof(void*));
        if (NULL != newData)
        {
            array->data = newData;
            array->capacity = capacity;
            return 1; // 1 = "true" in C and indicates success.
        }
        return 0; // 0 = "false" in C and indicates failure...
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
typedef void (*PointerArrayElementFree_t)(void *element);

int PointerArrayResize(PointerArray_t *array, size_t newSize, void* value, PointerArrayElementFree_t elementFree)
{
    if (NULL == array) return 0;
    if (NULL == elementFree) return 0;

    if (newSize < array->size)
    {
        for (size_t index = newSize; index < array->size; index++)
        {
            elementFree(array->data[index]);
        }
        array->size = newSize;
        return 1;
    }
    else if (newSize > array->size)
    {
        size_t oldSize = array->size;
        if (PointerArrayReserve(array, newSize))
        {
            for (size_t index = oldSize; index < newSize; index++)
            {
                array->data[index] = value;
            }
            array->size = newSize;
            return 1;
        }
        return 0; // Reserve() failed, so this function also failed.
    }
    else
        return 1; // oldSize == newSize - nothing to do.
}

int PointerArrayInitializeWithCapacity(PointerArray_t *array, size_t initialCapacity)
{
    PointerArrayInitialize(array);
    return PointerArrayReserve(array, initialCapacity);
}

int PointerArrayPushBack(PointerArray_t *array, void*element)
{
    if (PointerArrayReserve(array, array->size + 1))
    {
        array->data[array->size] = element;
        array->size++;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int PointerArrayClear(PointerArray_t *array, PointerArrayElementFree_t elementFree)
{
    if (NULL == elementFree) return 0;
    if (NULL == array) return 0;

    for (size_t index = 0; index < array->size; index++)
    {
        elementFree(array->data[index]);
        array->data[index] = NULL;
    }
    array->size = 0;
    return 1;
}

int PointerArrayUninitialize(PointerArray_t *array, PointerArrayElementFree_t elementFree)
{
    if (PointerArrayClear(array, elementFree))
    {
        free(array->data);
        array->data = NULL;
        array->capacity = 0;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Nothing special here. A dynamic array of void pointers with the usual operations.

Next, while not 100% fitting your problem (I felt it would cost me more time to do it to the letter), the n-ary tree implementation. It is as stated above NOT ready to function as a graph.

Also, I took the liberty to assume a form of grammar along the line:

```
<Material> ::= <Count> <Name> <Size>
            |  <Count> <Name>
```

Parsing this production, the parser would first find a number (e.g. 2 wheels), then the Name of the material (wheel), then optionally measurements (e.g. Nuts[0.15]).

The alternative grammar closer to your question would be harder to handle later on when the AST is used by an application and is also overly complicated:

```
<Material> ::= <Count> <Name> <Size>
            | <Count> <Name>
            | <Name>
            | <Name> <Size>
```

This hints that if you have influence on the grammar of your input text, you could improve it some.

So, here the ComponentTree code, which has the above mentioned constraints.

```
enum NodeContentType
{
    EMPTY = 0
,   NUMBER = 1
,   NAME = 2
};

typedef struct NodeContent_tag
{
    NodeContentType type;
    union
    {
        float number;
        char *name;
    };
} NodeContent_t;

typedef struct ComponentNode_tag
{
    NodeContent_t content;
    ComponentNode_tag * parent;
    PointerArray_t children;
} ComponentNode_t;

void ComponentNodeFree(ComponentNode_t *node)
{
    // Clean up anything heap based in NodeContent_t.
    switch (node->content.type)
    {
    case NAME:
        free(node->content.name);
        node->content.name = NULL;
        node->content.type = EMPTY;
        break;
    default:
        // nothing to do.
        break;
    }

    // Free all the children below this node recursively.
    PointerArrayUninitialize(&node->children, (PointerArrayElementFree_t)ComponentNodeFree);
    free(node);
}
typedef struct ComponentTree_tag
{
    ComponentNode_t root;
} ComponentTree_t;

void ComponentTreeInitialize(ComponentTree_t *tree)
{
    tree->root.content.type = EMPTY;
    PointerArrayInitialize(&tree->root.children);
    tree->root.parent = NULL;
}

ComponentNode_t *ComponentTreeRoot(ComponentTree_t *tree)
{
    return &tree->root;
}

void ComponentTreeClear(ComponentTree_t *tree)
{
    if (NULL != tree)
    {
        PointerArrayClear(&tree->root.children,(PointerArrayElementFree_t)ComponentNodeFree);
    }
}

void ComponentTreeUninitialize(ComponentTree_t *tree)
{
    if (NULL != tree)
    {
        PointerArrayUninitialize(&tree->root.children, (PointerArrayElementFree_t)ComponentNodeFree);
    }
}

ComponentNode_t *ComponentTreeCreateEmptyNode()
{
    ComponentNode_t *node = (ComponentNode_t*)malloc(sizeof(ComponentNode_t));
    if (NULL != node)
    {
        node->content.type = EMPTY;
        node->parent = NULL;
        PointerArrayInitialize(&node->children);
    }
    return node;
}

ComponentNode_t *ComponentTreeCreateNameNode(const char *name)
{
    ComponentNode_t *node = (ComponentNode_t*)malloc(sizeof(ComponentNode_t));
    if (NULL != node)
    {
        node->content.type = NAME;
        node->content.name = _strdup(name);
        assert(NULL != node->content.name); 
        if (NULL == node->content.name)
        {
            free(node);
            return NULL;
        }
        node->parent = NULL;
        PointerArrayInitialize(&node->children);
    }
    return node;
}

ComponentNode_t *ComponentTreeCreateNumberNode(float number)
{
    ComponentNode_t *node = (ComponentNode_t*)malloc(sizeof(ComponentNode_t));
    if (NULL != node)
    {
        node->content.type = NUMBER;
        node->content.number = number;
        node->parent = NULL;
        PointerArrayInitialize(&node->children);
    }
    return node;
}


int ComponentTreeJoin(ComponentTree_t *tree, ComponentNode_t *where, ComponentNode_t *child)
{
    if (NULL == child) return 0;
    if (NULL != child->parent) return 0; // is already in a tree.
    if (NULL == tree) return 0;
    if (NULL == where)
    {
        where = &tree->root;
    }
    child->parent = where;
    return PointerArrayPushBack(&where->children, child);
}
```

It might look a bit funny at first glance that the `ComponentTree_t *tree` parameter exists in `ComponentTreeJoin()`. But rather, the `CompoenentTreeCreateXXXNode()` functions should have it as well. Why? Because it is likely that later on someone wants to have a function like `ComponentTree_t *ComponentTreeFromNode(ComponentNode_t *node)` or a `ComponentNode_t *ComponentTreeGetRoot(ComponentNode_t *node)`.

Last not least, manual assembly of the tree could look like this (incomplete, this answer is already length):

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    ComponentTree_t bikeTree;
    ComponentTreeInitialize(&bikeTree);
    ComponentNode_t * nutSize = ComponentTreeCreateNumberNode(0.15f);
    ComponentNode_t * nut = ComponentTreeCreateNameNode("NUT");
    ComponentTreeJoin(&bikeTree, nut, nutSize);
    ComponentNode_t *nutCount = ComponentTreeCreateNumberNode(7.0f);
    ComponentTreeJoin(&bikeTree, nutCount, nut);
    ComponentNode_t * boltSize = ComponentTreeCreateNumberNode(0.1f);
    ComponentNode_t * bolt = ComponentTreeCreateNameNode("BOLT");
    ComponentTreeJoin(&bikeTree, bolt, boltSize);
    ComponentNode_t * boltCount = ComponentTreeCreateNumberNode(5.0f);
    ComponentTreeJoin(&bikeTree, boltCount, bolt);
    ComponentNode_t * axle = ComponentTreeCreateNameNode("AXLE");
    ComponentTreeJoin(&bikeTree, axle, nutCount);
    ComponentTreeJoin(&bikeTree, axle, boltCount);
    ComponentNode_t *axleCount = ComponentTreeCreateNumberNode(1.0f);
    ComponentTreeJoin(&bikeTree, axleCount, axle);
    ComponentNode_t *gearSize = ComponentTreeCreateNumberNode(25.0f);
    ComponentNode_t *gear = ComponentTreeCreateNameNode("GEAR");
    ComponentTreeJoin(&bikeTree, gear, gearSize);
    ComponentNode_t *gearCount = ComponentTreeCreateNumberNode(2.0f);
    ComponentTreeJoin(&bikeTree, gearCount, gear);
    ComponentNode_t *hub = ComponentTreeCreateNameNode("HUB");
    ComponentTreeJoin(&bikeTree, hub, gearCount);
    ComponentTreeJoin(&bikeTree, hub, axleCount);
    ComponentNode_t *hubCount = ComponentTreeCreateNumberNode(1.0f);
    ComponentTreeJoin(&bikeTree, hubCount, hub);
    ComponentNode_t * spokeSize = ComponentTreeCreateNumberNode(120.0f);
    ComponentNode_t * spoke = ComponentTreeCreateNameNode("SPOKE");
    ComponentTreeJoin(&bikeTree, spoke, spokeSize);
    ComponentNode_t * spokeCount = ComponentTreeCreateNumberNode(1.0f);
    ComponentTreeJoin(&bikeTree, spokeCount, spoke);
    ComponentNode_t * axle1 = ComponentTreeCreateNameNode("AXLE");
    ComponentNode_t * axle1Count = ComponentTreeCreateNumberNode(2.0f);
    ComponentTreeJoin(&bikeTree, axle1Count, axle1);
    // ...
    ComponentNode_t * wheel = ComponentTreeCreateNameNode("WHEEL");
    ComponentTreeJoin(&bikeTree, wheel, axle1Count);
    ComponentTreeJoin(&bikeTree, wheel, spokeCount);
    ComponentTreeJoin(&bikeTree, wheel, hubCount);
    ComponentNode_t * wheelCount = ComponentTreeCreateNumberNode(2.0f);
    ComponentTreeJoin(&bikeTree, wheelCount, wheel);
    ComponentNode_t *bike = ComponentTreeCreateNameNode("BIKE");
    ComponentTreeJoin(&bikeTree, bike, wheelCount);
    ComponentNode_t *bikeCount = ComponentTreeCreateNumberNode(1.0f);
    ComponentTreeJoin(&bikeTree, bikeCount, bike);
    // .. frame branch omitted .. 
    ComponentTreeJoin(&bikeTree, NULL, bikeCount);
    ComponentTreeUninitialize(&bikeTree);

    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
    return 0;
}
```

Summary:

- If it is really supposed to be a graph, not an n-ary tree, then someone chose the wrong terms.
- The dynamic array code mixed into the tree implementation would make the code less testable and readable.
- If a dynamic array of pointers as kids-list is used or a singly linked list is not really fundamental. Probably a list would be better suited, since most nodes in the example input only have 1 child anyway and the difference is marginal. The current implementation of the array is also not saving the amount of heap operations (but it could, if default capacity were not programmed to be 0 but maybe 1 or 2 or another opportune value).
- The `main()` code shows how the tree is constructed in not exactly the order a parser traversing the input text would produce. (I sometimes went right to left instead of 100% left to right).
- The code shown here does not treat the number of material items as a member of the Node but it produces a number node on top of the material name node. This can but need not necessarily be beneficial as it completely depends on how the grammar is defined and on the type of parser etc. And this is often the case. How the AST eventually looks like is also driven by parser decisions made.